# google tts api for turkish

Tags: php, google-translate, text-to-speech

I was create a page which is read by google tts api. But the words does not translated correctly on my page. When, I translate the same phrase in google translate, it's perfectly translate. Note: I'm talking about sounds.

I'm getting the mp3 with CURL and "tl" paramater is "tr".

```
http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=tr&q="some turkish text"
```

So what do you think guys, what's my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the problem while clicking to a link at your page that redirects to Google's Translate URL?
If so this is because Google prevents all request that come with a referrer. Try obtaining the audio with PHP or some other backend technology.

Google's TTS is not a documented API and it is also limited to 100 characters within the **q** parameter.

Comment: Yes, google prevents all request coming from outside. But I used CURL for this action. I achieved to get mp3 file from google. There was a differences between google translate and my code. I tried to same phrase to speech but result wasn't same.

Comment: I tried both HTTP and CURL and both worked with this text: `http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=tr&q=%22yaz%C4%B1k%20veya%20do%C4%9Fal%20ki,%20t%C3%BCm%20d%C3%BCnyan%C4%B1n%20%C3%B6nemsedi%22`
and 
`curl -A "Mozilla" "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=tr&q=http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=tr&q=%22yaz%C4%B1k%20veya%20do%C4%9Fal%20ki,%20t%C3%BCm%20d%C3%BCnyan%C4%B1n%20%C3%B6nemsedi" > audio.mp3`


Are you sure you are not exceeding the 100 character limit?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I didnt exceed the limit. I send just 15 or 20 characters.

Comment: My script doesn't give any error. Just mp3 file is not same as google. So I can't send any part of my code, I have to send all of my code :)

Comment: But your script will eventually end up calling google, right? Could you provide us with that line that calls google?

Comment: `$url = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=".$text;
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
   $return = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   file_put_contents($put_file, $return);`